# Mysql - JOIN two tables group by 2 dates

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables that are not linked by a foreign key but that I would like to join.

Here are the two functional SQL queries I would like to join:

```
SELECT DATE(added) as 'day', COUNT(*) as 'TopicSub' 
FROM user_subscription 
WHERE topic_id = 39 
GROUP BY DATE(added)


SELECT DATE(date) as 'day', COUNT(*) as 'QSub' 
FROM user_submitted_q 
WHERE question_id IN (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE topic_id = 39) 
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

These two queries return a result including the total number of entries grouped by days.

First concern the days of the two queries do not necessarily match (There are no entries for all the days of the period), I would like to merge the results and have 0 if the other column does not include an equivalent date.

After a lot of unsuccessful attempts with all possible joints, I found this query that might work on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT DATE(date) as 'day', COUNT(*) as 'QSub' 
     FROM user_submitted_q 
     WHERE question_id IN (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE topic_id = 39) 
     GROUP BY DATE(date)) AS q1 
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    (SELECT DATE(added) as 'day', COUNT(*) as 'TopicSub' 
     FROM user_subscription 
     WHERE topic_id = 39 
     GROUP BY DATE(added)) AS q2 ON q1.day = q2.day 
ORDER BY 
    day
```

But unfortunately I use Mysql5.7

Here is the desired result:

```
Date       | QSub | TopicSub
-----------+------+---------
2018-02-09 |   5  |   1
2018-02-19 |  19  |  13
2018-02-21 |  12  |   1
2018-02-22 |  43  |   0
2018-02-25 |   0  |   1
```

Sample `user_submitted_q` data:

```
+----+---------+-------------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
| id | user_id | question_id | result | date                | ip             |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 |       2 |         436 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:13:15 | 176.159.30.253 |
|  2 |       2 |         409 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:13:15 | 176.159.30.253 |
|  3 |       3 |         651 | wrong  | 2018-02-09 00:13:53 | 77.136.14.187  |
|  4 |       3 |         651 | wrong  | 2018-02-09 00:13:53 | 77.136.14.187  |
|  5 |       1 |          96 | wrong  | 2018-02-09 00:21:51 | 77.69.200.124  |
|  6 |       1 |          24 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:21:51 | 77.69.200.124  |
|  7 |       1 |          25 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:21:51 | 77.69.200.124  |
|  8 |       1 |          96 | wrong  | 2018-02-09 00:26:52 | 77.69.200.124  |
|  9 |       1 |          24 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:26:52 | 77.69.200.124  |
| 10 |       1 |          25 | good   | 2018-02-09 00:26:52 | 77.69.200.124  |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+---------------------+----------------+
```

Sample user_subscription data:

```
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | topic_id | added               |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  8 |       1 |       39 | 2018-02-09 00:27:30 |
|  9 |       4 |       47 | 2018-02-09 00:42:34 |
| 10 |       4 |       19 | 2018-02-09 00:42:34 |
| 11 |       5 |       47 | 2018-02-09 00:54:14 |
| 13 |       6 |       47 | 2018-02-09 01:00:23 |
| 14 |       6 |       19 | 2018-02-09 01:00:23 |
| 17 |       8 |       47 | 2018-02-09 01:06:50 |
| 18 |       8 |       19 | 2018-02-09 01:06:50 |
| 19 |       9 |       47 | 2018-02-09 01:08:33 |
| 20 |       9 |       19 | 2018-02-09 01:08:33 |
+----+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Nice to see a desired result , would you like to add sample data from which this is derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t order by dt;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-02 |
| 2018-01-03 |
| 2018-01-03 |
| 2018-01-04 |
| 2018-01-04 |
+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t1 order by dt;
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2018-01-02 |
| 2018-01-03 |
| 2018-01-04 |
| 2018-01-05 |
| 2018-01-05 |
| 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-06 |
| 2018-01-07 |
| 2018-01-07 |
+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select tu.dt,(select count(*) from t where t.dt = tu.dt) tdt, 
    (Select count(*) from t1 where t1.dt = tu.dt) t1dt 
from
(
select dt from t
union
select dt from t1
) tu;
```

Will establish all dates spanning both tables then the sub queries will count them.

```
+------------+------+------+
| dt         | tdt  | t1dt |
+------------+------+------+
| 2018-01-01 |    1 |    0 |
| 2018-01-02 |    1 |    1 |
| 2018-01-03 |    2 |    1 |
| 2018-01-04 |    2 |    1 |
| 2018-01-05 |    0 |    2 |
| 2018-01-06 |    0 |    2 |
| 2018-01-07 |    0 |    2 |
+------------+------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

My SQL does not support full outer joins but you can simulate that behavior as follows:

```
Select Col1, Col2, ...
From Table1
Left Join Table 2 on Table1.col = Table2.col

Union

Select Col1, Col2, ...
From Table 1
Right Join Table 2 on Table1.col = Table2.col
```

If you care to preserve duplicate rows you would change the Union to a Union All